# Inserting values from GridView to database table is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When I click on `okScheduleBtn` button the values from the gridview are not being inserted to database table.

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void okScheduleBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr1))
            {
                conn.Open();
                for (int i = 0; i < ProofsDueGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[abcd] ([aaa], [bbb], [ccc], [ddd], [eee], [fff], [ggg], [hhh], [iii) values (@[aaa], @[bbb], @[ccc], @[ddd], @[eee], @[fff], @[ggg], @[hhh], @[iii])", conn);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@[aaa]", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ProofsDueGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("[@bbb]", SqlDbType.Date).Value = ProofsDueGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@[ccc]", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ProofsDueGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@[ddd]", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ProofsDueGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@[eee]", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ProofsDueGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("[@fff]", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ProofsDueGridView.Rows[i].Cells[5];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@[ggg]", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ProofsDueGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@[hhh]", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ProofsDueGridView.Rows[i].Cells[7];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@[iii]", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = ProofsDueGridView.Rows[i].Cells[8];

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                conn.Close();

            }
          //ProofsDueGridView.Rows.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

ASPX:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<table>
                                <tr>
                                        <td class="tablefont">

                                                <asp:GridView ID="ProofsDueGridView" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" Width="75%"
                                                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Job No." DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ProofsDueGridView_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                    <Columns>
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="aaa" HeaderText="aaa" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="aaa">
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="bbb" HeaderText="bbb" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="bbb">
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ccc" HeaderText="ccc" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ccc">
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddd" HeaderText="ddd" SortExpression="ddd">
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="eee" HeaderText="eee" SortExpression="eee">
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="fff" HeaderText="fff" SortExpression="fff">
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                                         <asp:BoundField DataField="ggg" HeaderText="ggg" SortExpression="ggg">
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                                          <asp:BoundField DataField="hhh" HeaderText="hhh" SortExpression="hhh">
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                                           <asp:BoundField DataField="iii" HeaderText="iii" SortExpression="iii">
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                                    </Columns>
                                                </asp:GridView>
                                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:lllConnectionString %>"
                                                    SelectCommand="SELECT distinct hh AS[aaa], CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), bbb, 101) AS[bbb], CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ccc, 101) AS[ccc], ll AS[ddd], oo AS [eee], cc AS [fff], ss AS [ggg], qq AS [hhh], dd AS [iii] FROM ppp )"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                                <asp:Button ID="okScheduleBtn" runat="server" Text="OK TO SCHEDULE" />

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Why are the values not inserted into the database?

Comment: Describe "not working". Is there an exception? Did you step through the code with a debugger? What line gets reached? Also, make sure you format your question for better readability.

Comment: reformulated the problem description for clarification and asked a precise question